# how to include html code in portal_normal.vm

Tags: liferay-theme, liferay-ide

I am using Life-ray 6.2 CE GA2 and liferay ide eclipse 2.2.1 ga2.

How can I include html in portal_normal.vm in custom theme in eclipse?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't give any other information, I'm assuming that you're building your theme with Ant. In the project structure, you'll have a folder `_diffs` (from memory, might be in singular), where you duplicate the complete structure of the theme.

So the file that you'll need to edit is (something like) `_diffs/templates/portal_normal.vm`. It will be copied during the build process to `templates/portal_normal.vm` - while you didn't create the file yourself, you can copy this version from the underlying theme template into your `_diffs` folder to have a starting point. Anything that you're editing outside of the `_diffs` folder will be overwritten during the build process.